# How to sort rows of a matrix based on frequency of the elements of one column?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I tried using sortrows function in Matlab. Is there any way using this function or any idea to sort rows of a matrix based on frequency of elements of a column of that matrix.

As an example: I have this matrix

```
matrix = [1 3 1;
          1 4 2;
          2 5 4;
          3 2 3; 
          5 5 4; 
          5 3 3; 
          4 3 2; 
          4 2 3; 
          3 6 4; 
          2 4 3];
```

I would like to get something similar to this:

```
sorted_based_on_3rd_col = [2 4 3;
                           3 2 3;
                           4 2 3;
                           5 3 3;
                           2 5 4;
                           3 6 4;
                           5 5 4;
                           1 4 2;
                           4 3 2;
                           1 3 1]
```

which is sorted based most frequent element on third column.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is the order chosen for the same number? How are the first 4 items from `sorted_based_on_3rd_col ` ordered?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actually there is no diffrence for this output. I think I can later sort them by first column or second one. Right?

Comment: You can not tell an algorithm "and with this do whatever you want". Choose a way you want them ordered!

Comment: Possibly something like [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), and then construct a fourth column containing a lookup on accumarray, sort by the fourth column, then remove the fourth column afterwards. (sorry no code.)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ok. The first 4 items should be sorted based on the first column in ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of elements with equal frequency, this can be done like so:

```
>> freq = accumarray(matrix(:,3), 1);
>> [~, ind] = sort(freq(matrix(:, 3)), 1, 'descend');  % index that sorts matrix
>> matrix(ind, :)  % reshuffle matrix to sort

ans =

     3     2     3
     5     3     3
     4     2     3
     2     4     3
     2     5     4
     5     5     4
     3     6     4
     1     4     2
     4     3     2
     1     3     1
```

If you do care, you need to pre-sort the matrix before anything else. Since matlab's sort is [stable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/247440), this will preserve the order of items that are equal in the second sort.

```
>> matrix = sortrows(matrix, 1)

matrix =

     1     3     1
     1     4     2
     2     5     4
     2     4     3
     3     2     3
     3     6     4
     4     3     2
     4     2     3
     5     5     4
     5     3     3

>> freq = accumarray(matrix(:,3),1);
>> [~, ind] = sort(freq(matrix(:,3)), 1, 'descend');
>> matrix(ind, :)

ans =

     2     4     3
     3     2     3
     4     2     3
     5     3     3
     2     5     4
     3     6     4
     5     5     4
     1     4     2
     4     3     2
     1     3     1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
x = matrix(:,3);
[c,b] = histc(x,unique(x))
[~,idx] = sort(c(b),'descend')
out = matrix(idx,:)
```

Comment: Second output of `histc`-- well thought!

Comment: @thewaywewalk thank you very much for your answer. It is completely correct and useful but I have only one choice for the best answer.